# Reset Neo4j browser styles

Tags: macos, neo4j, desktop-application, grass-file

I imported a .grass file to play around with styles, broke something along the way, and decided I'd just as soon revert to the default Neo4j Browser styles.

How can I *uninstall* the .grass file I installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You can reset to the default styles with `:style reset`

[ https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization ]

Comment: Pro tip: You can also use `:style` and if you click the little fire extinguisher in the bottom right corner of the browser block, it'll also reset the formatting